# How do I set a param in a controller action via a partial parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

experts,

I'm building a small app, that shall organize objectives into categories. On the categories index page, I wan't to show a form to add new objectives that directly belong to the category. In forms on other pages, there might be a selector for the category.

These are both models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :objectives
...

class Objective < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :description, :title
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
...
```

Here I pass the category_id into the form:

```
<%= render partial: "shared/objective_cat_form", locals: {category: category.id} %>
```

This is the form that is displayed for each category:

```
<%= form_for(@new_objective) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @new_objective %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Add new objective..." %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :category_id, :value => category %>
    <%= f.submit "New Objective", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And finally, here is the controller to create a new objective:

```
class ObjectivesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    Rails.logger.debug params.inspect
    @objective = current_user.objectives.build(params[:objective])

    if params[:category_id] != nil
      @objective.category_id = params[:category_id]
    end

    if @objective.save
      flash[:success] = "Objective added"
    else
      flash[:success] = "Error"
    end
    redirect_to categories_path
  end
...
```

This is the hash, that is passed to the controller:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"szGt358HWs2XZ4tss2M6cetx68axJB2Vq6dzHU608Dw=",
"objective"=>{"title"=>"Fancy title"}, "category_id"=>"{:value=>42}", "commit"=>"New
Objective", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"objectives"}
```

In the controller, I need another way to set the category_id into the new object, the current code doesn't work. How should I do this? I don't feel that this is "The Rails Way". I've read several tutorials and books, but I couldn't figure out how this should be done. Is there a way to get the category_id directly into the "objective"-hash?

I think that I can't use nested resources here, while I also wan't to create objectives outside the categories pages.

Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `Objective` already `belongs_to :category` then the Objective model have a `category_id`, try change your view from

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :category_id, :value => category %>
```

to

```
<%= f.hidden_field :category_id, :value => category %>
```

This way your "objective" hash should have the `category_id` inside it, give it a try.

Comment: I knew it would be that easy :) The solution works perfect, thank you!